# Calculating percentage of points closest to each census tract

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance

Hi if anyone can offer advice on this it would be amazing: I have a layer of geocoded addresses around a central point. I am trying to classify census blocks in the area by the percentage of these addresses that are closer to the centroid of each census block than they are to the central point. Doing it for one census block is easy - is there a way to automate the process for 1000+ blocks?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you've done already for one census block.

Comment: Suggest you amend your question and upload a few images of what you are trying to achieve?